# Как при объединении (merge) фреймов не учитывать NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

Есть 2 df - слияние происходит на 2 столбцам: 1 столбец всегда имеет соответствие и не может быть пустым(но может повторяться), еще 1 столбец может иметь значение, а может быть равен nan. Причем это может быть как в 1 df, так и в другом.

Мне необходимо объединить их между собой следуя правилам:
Если у 2 столбца текущее значение nan, то его необходимо объединить с любым значением, а не только nan, как это идет по дефолту. Причем правило действует в обе стороны.
Например 1 df - DB:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 df - VEN:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и я хочу получить результирующий df:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я могу их объединить по 1 полю:

`pd.merge(left=DB, right=VEN, how='left',on=['ID'])`

но как объединить по 2 полям учитывая вышеописанную логику я не знаю.

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе данные в виде текста или CSV, чтобы можно было скопировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [26]: d1
Out[26]:
   ID SOURCE
0   1    AAA
1   2    NaN
2   3    BBB

In [27]: d2
Out[27]:
   ID SOURCE VENUE
0   1    NaN    X1
1   2    CCC    X2
2   3    BBB    X3
3   4    NaN    X4
4   5    DDD    X5

In [28]: res = d1.merge(d2, on='ID', how='outer', suffixes=['', '2'])

In [29]: res['SOURCE'] = res['SOURCE'].combine_first(res.pop('SOURCE2'))

In [30]: res
Out[30]:
   ID SOURCE VENUE
0   1    AAA    X1
1   2    CCC    X2
2   3    BBB    X3
3   4    NaN    X4
4   5    DDD    X5
```